# A Higher r-squared always implies a reduction in MAE and RMSE?

Tags: machine-learning, r-squared, rms, mae

I apply 2 different machine learning models in my data, a Multiple Linear Regression and Random Forest. The results were bellow:

[image]

Why the MAE and RMSE are higher for a higher R-squared? Both models were tested in the same test set but with different input varibales

Comment: How do you compute $R^2$ for random forests?

Comment: I second the question from @utobi. [Not everyone agrees about how to calculate $R^2$ in every situation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) // MAE is a separate metric, and there is not expectation that it should move with measures of square loss.

Comment: @utobi r2_score(test_labels,predictions)

Comment: @Dave r2_score(test_labels,predictions) where the test_labels are my true values, and predictions the model prediction

Comment: What is the equation behind `r2_score`?

Comment: Are you calculating all of MAE, RMSE, $R^2$ on the same data?

Comment: @StephanKolassa yes

Comment: @RichardHardy  r2_score(test_labels,predictions) where the test_labels are my true values, and predictions the model prediction

Comment: @AliceSilva, that is still not an equation. A name of a function does not automatically tell me what exactly the function does.

Comment: @RichardHardy  1 - residual sum of square / total sum of squares.

Comment: Of which squares?

Comment: @Dave https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html you can see here the documentation of the metric

Comment: I’m familiar with the function. What are you inputting into it?

Comment: @Dave i just remember that my variables inputs are not the same this can mean something?

Comment: @Dave i input the true values, and the predicted values by the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’ve described can’t happen in math, so there’s either a missing detail, a bug in your code causing you to input something other than what you intend to input, or something wrong with the Python function (the last of which I find unlikely).

I [disagree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) with this Python implementation of $R^2$, but for the same data set, $R^2_{1,sklearn}>R^2_{2,sklearn}\iff MSE_2>MSE_2\iff R^2_{1,Dave}>R^2_{2,Dave}$. This is because $R^2$, either in the implementation you use or that way I prefer, is a strictly decreasing function of MSE.

$$R^2=1-\dfrac{MSE}{denominator}$$

(This denominator is some kind of sum of squares that is related to a model that predicts the same value every time. Your function and I disagree on what the one value should be, but you could pick $5$ or $17$ or $\pi$ as the denominator, and MSE and that definition of $R^2$ should move in opposite directions.)

If you evaluate the $R^2$ of two different models but on the same data, the denominator stays the same. Thus, increasing/decreasing $R^2$ corresponds to decreasing/increasing MSE.

(If your implementation of an MSE calculation involves an $n-p$ denominator instead of $n$ or $n-1$, then the above does not apply. This could be the kind of missing detail I mentioned in the last sentence of my first paragraph.)

MAE is a totally different metric that need not increase/decrease with an increase/decrease in MSE or a decrease/increase in $R^2$. In [this linked answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/569874/247274), I give examples where an MSE increase/decrease is accompanied by an MAE decrease/increase.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the answer, can you just explain a little bit more about the MSE calculation involving n-p instead of n and n-1? What does the p means in this case and can you show that formula?

Comment: @AliceSilva the $p$ refers to the number of parameters in a linear regression model, and it can be thought of as a way to penalize using a large number of parameters. For further details, you might consider posting a new question so others can benefit from the answer, rather than burying important material in the comments of a fairly unrelated question.