# What metric should I use for a Regression model with a gamma distributed target?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, optimization, gamma-distribution, metric

### Background

I'm building a regression model on insurance data to predict the losses associated with a policy. I'm running an [Optuna](https://optuna.org/) optimisation function to help me with this, but I'm struggling with what metric to use to score the model. The metric defines the course of the optimisation, so I want to get it right.

The model I'm currently using is the [`LGBMRegressor`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html), and the losses are approximately distributed via a gamma distribution.

So far I've used R^2, but I've read that's [not a great goodness-of-fit metric](https://www.quantics.co.uk/blog/r-we-squared-yet-why-r-squared-is-a-poor-metric-for-goodness-of-fit).

### Question

What metric should I use to score my regression model?

Comment: The gamma distribution is a whole family with radically different shapes depending on the values of its two parameters. What shape are your losses?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a point prediction, not (say) a predictive density, correct? ([This](https://dfep.netlify.app/sec-forecasting-workflow) may be helpful.) If so, [this thread may be what you are looking for](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45875/1352). Incidentally, it is not necessarily the case that you should use the same evaluation metric in training as later on in evaluation, [see here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/568752/1352).

Comment: @PeterFlom I'll calculate and update.

Comment: @StephanKolassa yes, I'm looking for a point prediction, although a density would be interesting too. Thank you  for the links!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the (negative) likelihood of the distribution as your loss function.  You can also turn it into a pseudo r2 for easier interpretability ( and negative likelihood is a 1:1 relation to pseudo r2).

I highly recommend xgboostlss / lightgbmlss for that regression task.
https://github.com/StatMixedML/XGBoostLSS
https://github.com/StatMixedML/LightGBMLSS

Somewhat related:
Working in the field of insurance, I have my doubts that policies are gamma distributed without zero-inflation ( does every policy have a 100% chance to pay out >$0).  If you actually do have 0 payout I recommend using zero inflated lognormal distributions (and loss).  This is a popular choice in customer lifetime value modeling , and transfers very nicely to policy pricing. See here fir details and implementation ( including loss)
https://github.com/google/lifetime_value

In xgboostlss world this is the ZALN distribution.

Comment: Thank you, those githubs look really interesting! Are these tools commonly used in the insurance industry? It looks like they allow you to flexibly create a distribution, is that correct? What do you mean by the "negative likelihood of your distribution"? Does that basically mean try and fit to a distribution and the loss is how poorly your distribution fits?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  See e.g. eq (3) and (4) int the LTV paper for the zero inflated lognormal negative log likelihood loss.